# pandas read_csv with pound sign in column headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to read data from a tab-delimited file where the 1st row contains column headers but the 1st character of that row is a `pound sign`/`octothorpe`/`hastag`/`#`.

The data looks like this:

```
#   year-month-day  spam    eggs
1956-01-31  11  21
1985-03-20  12  22
1940-11-22  13  23
```

`read_csv` makes 3 mistakes:  1.  It will include any leading pound signs either as its own unique column, or as the first character of the first column, causing too many columns or preserving whitespace, tabs and commas as part of the columnname, even when it's told that is the delimiter.  2.  Tabs, Whitespace, Commas, Singlequotes and Double quote delimiters will be randomly used as delimiters for columns, with a priority system not defined in the docs, and depending if the delimiter is next to whitespace, or not for example `'abc','xyz'` or `'abc', 'xyz'`
3.  If escape is defined as a backslash, then escaped characters will not be taken as literal.
4.  If you ask pandas to infer any of the above or header, all the above will be inferred incorrectly.

Looks like the only viable option is to 1: roll your own tell header read function then 2: tell pandas `read_csv` to ignore the header column.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to shift the column names by a single position to the left to account for the empty column getting created due to the removal of `#` char.

Then, remove the extra column whose values are all `NaN`.

```
def column_cleaning(frame):
    frame.columns = np.roll(frame.columns, len(frame.columns)-1)
    return frame.dropna(how='all', axis=1)

FILE_CONTENTS = """\
#   year-month-day  spam    eggs
1956-01-31  11  21
1985-03-20  12  22
1940-11-22  13  23
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(FILE_CONTENTS), delim_whitespace=True, escapechar="#")

column_cleaning(df)
```

[image]

Comment: for data that can have _either_ `#<tab>col_name` and `#<space>col_name` we can wrap your `column_cleaning` in an `if '' ==  frame.columns[0].strip():` and put EdChums `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` on the else block

Answer (score 6):

This gives the desired `DataFrame`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as  pd

FILE_CONTENTS = """\
# year-month-day    spam    eggs
1956-01-31  11  21
1985-03-20  12  22
1940-11-22  13  23
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(FILE_CONTENTS), delim_whitespace=True, escapechar='#')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

N.B. edited to include [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum)'s fix for the leading white-space in initial column, supplied in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485976/pandas-read-csv-with-pound-sign-in-column-headers#comment66290633_39485977).

And seems preferable to various kludges I tried along the lines of:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    header = f.readline()
cols = header.strip('#').split()
df = pd.read_csv(..., comment='#', names=cols)
```

edit: seeing [Nickil Maveli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6207849/nickil-maveli)'s answer i realize that I have to deal with both `#<space>year-month-day ...` *and*  `#<tab>year-month-day ...` in the file headers.
So we will need a combination of Nikil's and EdChum's approaches

Comment: this `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(FILE_CONTENTS), delim_whitespace=True,
                 escapechar='#', skipinitialspace=True)` with and without `skipinitialspace` param leaves a preceding space at `' year-month-day'`, it seems that it's ignored if you pass `escapeshar` param so you'd need to trim the leading spaces `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: minor point, but usually the code you want to improve on is included in the question